# How to set the icon of Action Button in Android Activity on run time?

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I have an Action Button in my ActionBar that will be basically be used to indicate the status of the Bluetooth service on the phone. I'm able to create this action button and toggle it's states and even change the icon from bluetooth_on.png to bluetooth_off.png but I don't know how to set the correct icon to begin with, based on the state of the Bluetooth service at the time when the activity is first launched.

I suppose I need to do something here:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

this is the code I'm working with so far:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_bluetooth) 
        {
            if(bluetoothStatus == false)
            {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                if(beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled())
                {
                    bluetoothStatus = true;
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.bluetooth_on);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                bluetooth_mgr.disable();
                bluetoothStatus = false;
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.bluetooth_off);
            }


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Ignore the beaconManager (I'm using the Estimotes beacons SDK). The boolean variable bluetoothStatus serves as my flag variable to check if bluetooth is ON or OFF. How can I use this to set the right icon in the action button at the time of the activity's launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you want to set the icon to the correct indicator at launch. Assuming that beaconManager is initialized in onCreate (or just before onCreateOptionsMenu is called), this should work for you.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    MenuItem item =  menu.findItem(R.id.action_bluetooth);
    if(item != null){
         if(beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled())
            {
                bluetoothStatus = true;
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.bluetooth_on);
            }else{
               item.setIcon(R.drawable.bluetooth_off);
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks so much :)